# Check if environment variable present while starting rails app or abort

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to check if an environment is set while starting my rails app. If it's not present I would like to abort with an error message.

Where would I put this check?

In a config file or routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Rails initialization starts from `config/environment`. That requires `config/application` and then loads the application which executes the initializers.

Depending on when in the initialization process you want to raise the error, I suggest adding it into `config/application` or an initializer.

`routes.rb` is definitely inappropriate unless the condition is directly related to routing.

Comment: I would use an initializer for that. You can find the official documentation at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files